# Angular2 http Post request results into 404

Tags: angular, http-post

I have to do login in angular2. If I push login I have an Error[image]

and manualy after call the link http://localhost:3000/idx-kk/app_dev.php/de/signon on browser I became Cannot GET /idx-kk/app_dev.php/de/signon
I tested my backand on SOAPUI and there work. what do I wrong?

my login.service.ts is

```js
 login(username, password, tenant): Observable<boolean> {
        let body = JSON.stringify({ user: username, password: password,tenant: tenant  });
        console.log(body);

        return this.http.post("idx-kk/app_dev.php/de/signon", body)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                    console.log(response);
            });
    }
```

and login.component.ts

```js
    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.loginService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password, this.model.tenant)
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result === true) {
                    // login successful
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                } else {
                    // login failed
                    this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you have CORS enabled (for development) and that you are allowing insecure connections (again for development only!). RE: SOAPUI: how can you stand to use such horrific thing?